# Remove value from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array JavaScript and a string :

```
var pool1 = ['ca','cahier','cartable','carte','cartographe','canape'];
var key1 = 'car';
```

What I am trying to do is, remove from the array all value that aren't containing `key1`.

To do so I've written this function :

```
function searchInPool(key, pool){
    for (i = 0; i < pool.length; i++) {
        var index = pool[i].indexOf(key);
        if (index > -1) {
            pool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    return pool;
}
```

It seems to be working, except that the final result gives me :

```
["cartable", "carte", "cartographe", "canape"]
```

It has succesfully removed `ca`and `cahier` but `canape` shouldn't be here since it doesn't contain `car` anyone can explain me what I've misunderstood from what I've written in my function ?

The final result expected is :

`["cartable", "carte", "cartographe"]`

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should reverse your loop `for (var i = pool.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {` because this way you'll account for the shortening length of the array which isn't happening in your example.

Comment: You call `splice()` with `index`, which is the position of `key1` in the string. It seems wrong to me.

Comment: Since answer is closed, I can't post answer. But issues with your code are: 1) you change the array `pool` while you are looping over it, which gives your strange results and 2) the index you use to remove an item is the index where your code finds the string `car`, and it should be the index of the item in the array and 3) the check `(index > -1)` actually tries to remove items that DO have `car` in them. It is reallyt pure luck that the other two items are removed correctly and that the right items stay in.

Comment: @Barmar I would vote to reopen this question. OP's question is NOT how to remove item from array (so not duplicate), but "explain what I have misunderstood". Maybe the question is more suitable for Code Review than SO, but I do not think is duplicate. Maybe OP could weigh in too with his opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
array.filter(e => !e.includes(key));
```

```js
var pool1 = ['ca', 'cahier', 'cartable', 'carte', 'cartographe', 'canape'];
var key1 = 'car';

var result = pool1.filter(e => !e.includes(key1));
console.log(result);
```

**ES5:**

```
var result = pool1.filter(function(el) {
    return el.indexOf(key1) === -1;
});
```

Comment: Is `Array#filter` available in all browsers? How to check that it works depending on browser versions?

Comment: @A.L [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility). To support older browsers the **ES5** approach should be used.

Comment: @A.L all browsers including IE9+. IE8 and less it's not compatible with this specification

Comment: I dont seem to really understand he ES5 approach, it is working but gives the opposite of what I need and dont know how to reverse it :/

Comment: @Nirnae `return el.indexOf(key1) !== -1;` `result` is the array that you should be using.

Comment: @Nirnae: I recommend to read the documentation of `.filter` and `.indexOf`. `.filter` returns a new array only containing those elements for which the callback returns `true`. `.indexOf` returns the fist position of a substring inside a string, or `-1` if the string does not contain the substring.